# Modify SSIS 2008 project -.dtsx

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008

I have a development server with SQL server 2017 Developer edition and integration service,

There is a SSIS project (.dtproj) I believe it was built using 2008 BIDS, So I want to do some changes/modification on that,

Do I need to install SQL server 2008 R2 Integration Service? Or Can I do this by only using BIDS 2008? and is there any other software's that I need to install.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using vs2017 then you need to install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do without upgrading

Comment: If you use VS2019, no need SSDT package installation is required